# .Include<> in EF Core causing System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following code:

```
_Db.AnalysisFileAnalysisConfigurations
    .Where(x => x.AnalysisConfigurationId == analysisConfiguraitonId)
    .Include(y => y.AnalysisFile)
    .ToList();
```

Which throws this error:

> `System.ObjectDisposedException`: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling `Dispose()` on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.`

I have used `Include` statement at multiple occasions in the same project and never had this error. Moreover, when I remove the `Include` clause, the code works fine. I am not sure what is the co-relation between include clause and my `dbContext` going out of scope.

Also, this only happens when I try to include `AnalysisFile`. AnalysisFileAnalysisConfigurations also includes `AnalysisConfigurations and cod below does not break at all`

```
_Db.AnalysisFileAnalysisConfigurations
    .Where(x => x.AnalysisConfigurationId == analysisConfiguraitonId)
    .Include(y => y.AnalysisConfiguration)
    .ToList();
```

Which make me think it is either AnalysisFile or the way relation between parent object and AnalysisFile have been established in DbContext.

It looks like following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AnalysisFileAnalysisConfiguration>()
                    .HasOne(bc => bc.AnalysisConfiguration)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.AnalysisConfigurationId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

                modelBuilder.Entity<AnalysisFileAnalysisConfiguration>()
                    .HasOne(bc => bc.AnalysisFile)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.AnalysisFileId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

                modelBuilder.Entity<AnalysisFileAnalysisConfiguration>()
                    .HasIndex(afac => new { afac.AnalysisConfigurationId, afac.AnalysisFileId })
                    .IsUnique();

                modelBuilder.Entity<AnalysisFileAnalysisConfiguration>()
                    .HasIndex(afac => afac.AnalysisConfigurationId);
```

Below is the stack trace of the exception thrown

`at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.IDbContextDependencies.get_StateManager()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContextDependencies.get_StateManager()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext.get_StateManager()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext.StartTracking(IEntityType entityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer valueBuffer)\n   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Illumina.GenomicMicroArrayService.Domain.DataAccess.AnalysisFileAnalysisConfigurationDataAccess.GetAnalysisFilesByAnalysisConfiguration(Int64 analysisConfiguraitonId) in /Users/Illumina/random/Stratus/Services/GenomicMicroArrayService/common/GenomicMicroArrayService.Domain/DataAccess/AnalysisFileAnalysisConfigurationDataAccess.cs:line 31`

As it can be seen both AnalysisFile and AnalysisConfiguration been defined in almost identical manner.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's nothing immediately obvious going wrong. What is the definition of `AnalysisFile`? Are you using lazy-loading? What happens to the `List<T>` returned from that query? I suspect that you have code that runs after `_Db` is disposed and it dereferences `AnalysisFile` if it's non-null and then uses a navigation-property on `AnalysisFile` that triggers lazy-loading and hence the `ObjectDisposedException`. You should disable lazy-loading anyway (as non-obvious side-effects are bad - and because lazy-loading properties is incompatible with `async` database code anyway)

Comment: @DaiI updated my original question with some more details. As per your suggestion, I removed all of the navigation properties from AnalysisFile as well. Still no resolution. But the problem is, as you suggested, with Analysisfile or may be the way it is configured

Comment: Can you provide [mre]? Or at least to start with exception stack trace.

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated with stack trace. Since there are multiple pieces involved here, I am trying to produce the `Minimal reproducible example`.

Comment: `ToListAsync` in the stack trace indicates async tracking query execution after db context disposal. Most probably some code is missing `await`.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Your hunch is 100% right. I did find a missing await in the call stack.

Comment: Just so that it is clear enough. There was a different error that the code was throwing. But while throwing the exception ,may be the dbcontext went out of scope because of missing await and ended up throwing error related to that.